# How to enforce a workflow ordering for GitHub Actions checks

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflow files with several jobs for each. The checks in a PR are mingled, see [image: the screenshot]

How to make GitHub sort the checks?

Note: the repo is https://github.com/keep-starknet-strange/madara

Comment: Why does the workflow ordering matter? If they're _dependent_ you could dispatch one from the other, see e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow.

Comment: I don't really _need_ it, I just would like to have it because it's confusing like that imho

Comment: As far as I'm aware GitHub offers no conflguration, it just reports them as they come in. So if you want them to appear in a particular consistent order, I think you'd have to _run them_ in that order.

Comment: Did you try renaming them in alphabetical order?

Comment: not sure to follow, as per my screenshot they're not alphabetically sorted, right?

Comment: You right, I missed some details. If they are spread among different workflows, then it might be possible with reusable workflows (although that's a yet quite immature feature imho), but I see it hard & messy to achieve; probably overkill. — You can have a parent workflow that has named & ordered jobs, that inherit specific job references [via the URI format (first one in the docs) of reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow).

Comment: > Why does the workflow ordering matter?
because of this for instance: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact/issues/53

Dispatching doesn't work in this case since the caller workflow does not finish until the dispatched workflow does.